# Find link and info into a div

Tags: php, regex

I need to get content of specific div for add in my database link and info to external website

HTML is like

```
<div class="last">
  <a href="...">test</a>
  <b>title</b>
</div>
<div class="last">
  <a href="...">test</a>
  <b>title</b>
</div>
```

I use this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
     $url2 = $href->getAttribute('u');

    echo $url . '<br />';
    echo $url2 . '<br />';
    echo $target_url . '<br />';

    //storeLink($url,$target_url);
    //echo "<br />Link stored: $url";
}
```

What is the regex for have only `a href` and `b` into all div `class=last` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
function get_string($string, $start, $end)
{
   $found = array();
   $pos = 0;
   while( true )
   {
      $pos = strpos($string, $start, $pos);
      if ($pos === false) 
      { // Zero is not exactly equal to false...
         return $found;
      }
       $pos += strlen($start);
       $len = strpos($string, $end, $pos) - $pos;
       $found[] = substr($string, $pos, $len);
    }
}

$html='<div class="last"><a href="...">test</a><b>title</b></div><div class="last"><a href="...">test</a><b>title</b></div>';
```

to get Anchor from Html

```
get_string($html,'class="last"','</a>');
```

similarly to extract  data

```
get_string($html,'<b>','</b>');
```